# Зависимость Text и Visibility TextBlock wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

Можно ли сделать TextBlock видимым в зависимости от тескта с помощью Xaml. Если текст есть то TextBlock Видим.

Comment: Если текста нет, то и скрывать нечего

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649906/wpf-condition-binding-versus-property-xamlparseexception-using-either ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Style.Triggers](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.triggers?view=netcore-3.1)

```xml
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>     
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: А если у меня уже установлено ```Style = "{StaticResource MaterialDesignHeadline6TextBlock}"```

Comment: @Qwerty `<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHeadline6TextBlock}">`